# How to query a datastore in a specific datacenter by name in pyvmomi

Tags: python-2.7, vmware, pyvmomi

I am querying a datastore with its name in vcenter using an example of pyvmomi sample code:

```
si = connect.SmartConnectNoSSL(host=192.168.1.2, user=Administrator,  pwd=password, port=443)
content = si.RetrieveContent()
container = content.viewManager.CreateContainerView(content.rootFolder, [vim.Datastore], True)

for c in container.view:
    if c.name == "datastore-01":
        vim_obj = c
        break
return vim_obj
```

This worked fine if there is only one datacenter. But if I have more than one datacenter with same name datastore in each of those datacenters, the query returns only first datastore it finds. I was able to find that the datstores are in `content.rootFolder.childEntity[].datastoreFolder.childEntity[]` path but wondering how to query for specific datastore in a datacenter.

Answer (score 1):

figured out a solution to my question. Posting if somebody else looking for an answer:

```
for c in container.view:                             
     if c.name == "datacenter-01":                 
         datastores = c.datastoreFolder.childEntity   
         for datastore in datastores:                 
             if datastore.name == "datastore-01":
                 vim_obj = datastore
                 break
return vim_obj
```